# using alarm(3) with out exit from program-- c++

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, centos

here is my code.

```
 #include<iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    while(true)
    {
    std::cout<<"enter string \n";
    alarm(3);
    getline(std::cin,str);
       // calling another function in some other class,
           and return to here (If not entered any string in 3 sec) 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

after 2 sec it is exiting from my program. But, i want to continue by calling another function and return to the same getline(). is it possible?? 
thanks

Comment: This was answered more than once in your other question.

Comment: not same -chris
observe once clearly, now i want to continue in that same program.
anyways just drop your ideas here 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read a [reference page of `alarm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/alarm.html) you will see that:

> The `alarm()` function shall cause the system to generate a `SIGALRM` signal for the process after the number of realtime seconds specified by seconds have elapsed.

You need to *catch* this `SIGALRM` signal, for example by using the [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html) system call.

Comment: sounds good. can u please explain me by giving a simple code of catching the alarm signal. i am not getting that reference(sorry).
thanks 
-Joachim Pileborg

Comment: @Rajendra The `sigaction` reference linked in my answer have a simple example on how to set up a signal handler for a signal. Just put the correct signal instead of `SIGINT` and don't set the `SA_RESTART` flag.

Comment: oh.. thnq -Joachim Pileborg
i'll have a look and get back to you.. thank you very much